# Avocado leaf problem

Tags: fungus, avocado, spider-mites

The leaves on my 1 year old avocado plant are showing some weird almost dusty grey spots near the veins.

The leaves stay like this for a while, then they start to curl inwards/down get really crispy and fall/break off from the plant.

The plant only survives because it's growing new leaves very fast. I'm however afraid it will not keep up during the winter.

Is this some sort of fungus or mites, or something else?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you need to look with a magnifying glass - under magnification, its impossible to see from these images what they are clearly,  but most  likely a sap sucking insect of some sort because of its distribution along veins in the leaf. Scale, mites, aphids, that sort of thing - does anything fly up in the air if you disturb a leaf or do these stay fixed in position?

Comment: I will try and look under magnification! When I disturb the leaf nothing flies away. They stay in the same position, i can only rub them away.

Comment: Not aphids then...

Comment: I spotted some white spider like insects on some other leaf, just a few 3/4. They don't seem to move. Could not take a picture of them because they are really small. The veins also seem to be going brown after a while. Could it be mites, what are the grey dusty spots children?

Comment: If its spider mites, you can usually see some bits of webbing, fine and minimal albeit, but they should be visible. To be honest. I'd hit it with some neem spray, particularly spraying underneath the leaves as well as the top, and repeat it a few days later if you see anything else. That enlarged image definitely shows eggs, doesn't it, and they may hatch out after you've treated with neem, so keep a check on it.

Comment: neem spray is new to me, i need to make it from neem oil. ill give it a try! Yes i think they are eggs, how ever can hardly find any spiders. is neem spray safe to use? what is the ratio, soap water neem oil?

Comment: Where are you in the world? Neem is very difficult to get in the UK other than just the neat oil, but in the States, neem sprays are sold... I'm afraid I've no experience of using neem nor how to mix it,  being in the UK, but this link should help you with that http://www.discoverneem.com/neem-insect-spray.html

Comment: I'm from the Netherlands, i ordered it online. And used your website link, i sprayed the leaves about three times now with a few days in between. Is there anything i need to look for? Or keep this up for another week? (leaves still drop while moving or spraying the plant)

Comment: Its no surprise its still losing leaves - whatever the problem was affected the sap stream and has damaged  the cells, so its not impossible that all the leaves will fall.I wouldn't spray any more though - just wait and see what happens,  it;ll either  recover or it won't. fingers crossed it does recover, but it might already have been too late when you finally treated the plant.

Comment: it lost all its leaves last winter, and got back again with spring. but now its high summer again, and its starting again, same problem.... again with neem spray or something else? like those sprays you find in shops against pests?

Comment: If the neem spray did the trick last time, use it again....